# log in Ubuntu(it's in vm box) using copssh in Window7 machine

Tags: virtualbox, window

Ip of Ubuntu is 10.0.2.15(got it by 'ifconfig'),but it seems be 169.254.107.82(got it by VirtualBox Host-Only Network ).....

And in Cmd of Windows,I can't ping to 10.0.2.15,but can ping to 169.254.107.82.

In Ubuntu,I can ping to 192.168.1.104,and log in it by 'ssh'.
Ip of Windows is 192.168.1.104.
@Mitesh thanks!
In Window7 machine,I installed copssh and Ubuntu( it's in vitrualbox) .

When I use copssh to log in my ubuntu ,some error appear:

```
$ ssh lime@169.254.107.82
warning:Permanerntly added '169.254.107.82' <ECDSA> to the list of know host.
Permission denied <keyborad-interactive>.
```

In ubuntu,the file of /etc/ssh/sshd_config is that:

```
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
 # HostKeys for protocol version 2
 HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
 HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
 HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
 UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
 KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

 # Logging
 SyslogFacility AUTH
 LogLevel INFO

 # Authentication:
 LoginGraceTime 120
 PermitRootLogin yes
  StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
 #AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
 # similar for protocol version 2
 HostbasedAuthentication no
 # Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
 #IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

 # To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
 PermitEmptyPasswords no

 # Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
 # some PAM modules and threads)
 ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

 # Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
  PasswordAuthentication yes

 # Kerberos options
 #KerberosAuthentication no
 #KerberosGetAFSToken no
 #KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
 #KerberosTicketCleanup yes

 # GSSAPI options
 #GSSAPIAuthentication no
  #GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

  X11Forwarding yes
 X11DisplayOffset 10
  PrintMotd no
 PrintLastLog yes
   TCPKeepAlive yes
  #UseLogin no
#MaxStartups 10:30:60
  #Banner /etc/issue.net

  # Allow client to pass locale environment variables
 AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

 Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
 # be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
  # PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
   # PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
  # the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
 # If  you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
 # PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
 # and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
 UsePAM yes
```

Comment: So is the Ubuntu setup a separate computer, or in a virtual box? If a virtual box, see [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html). Hope this is relevant... :-)

Comment: I'm confused by your setup... which system is the VM and which is the host device?  Also which system are you trying to reach, and which of the "systems" is being used to try and SSH into the system.

Comment: "sikaiwei" is your Windows username and you're using your Windows password?

Comment: Ubuntu is the VM,and Windows is the host device.From Windows to Unbuntu or from Ubuntu to Windows,both!

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand your problem, but i can suggest this video.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHAEsUL6rsw
I followed this steps and i success to login my windows 7 ssh server.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your VM Ubuntu OS Ip address (ifconfig).
check IP assign to your VM OS has same Ip group addresses, suppose in your case your VM IP is 192.168.1.103 and check for your machine IP (from your try to connect ) if they have different IP group like (192.168.0.0 -- OR 10.0.0.0 -- ).
Because some time windows create their NAT and and separate LAN group.

so if it so  then you need to change it.

Comment: Ip of Ubuntu is 10.0.2.15(got it by 'ifconfig'). Ip of Windows is 192.168.1.104.....But how I change it?